# how to set excel background color to light grey

Tags: java, excel, styles

I'm trying to set the excel color to light grey using below line

```
cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_25_PERCENT.getIndex());
```

but it doesn't seems to work...
I tried adding the below but I'm getting crazy dark background

```
cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

Any idea why it doesn't work for me?

I'm trying to get below grey color

[image]

Comment: record a macro of you setting things the way you like.  Then go look at the code for the macro and see what is used?

Comment: didnt understand your comment

Comment: when you record a macro, it generates the VBA code to do whatever it is your are doing in excel.   Its not not the most optimized code and it designed for a single run through.  So if you record yourself colouring the cells as you want, you can then go into the VBA editor and find the record macro and see the line of code that was used for colouring the cells

Comment: im not familiar with that but i will deferentially check that option. thanks.